# Magento 2.3.3 fails to open a specific product on Admin Panel / Backend

Tags: magento2.3.3

Magento 2.3.3 fails to open a specific products on Admin Panel. When clicked to open the products it throws below error after stucking for at least 5 minutes. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Increasing php_memory doesnt help as many reccomended. I have checked the products with the same issues, most are configurable products and variation atributes those supposed to be editable are not editable anymore.

We use data mapping extension to create products from a CSV file, this might be a result of duplicate data entry to database for an attribute or a corrupted database table etc. but still not sure what exactly has caused this problem.

OUTPUT:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: session_start():
> Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed in
> .../public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on
> line 208
>
> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: session_start(): Failed to decode
> session object. Session has been destroyed in
> .../public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on
> line 208

```
#1 session_start() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:208]
#2 Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php:167]
#3 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->start() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:140]
#4 Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000386f16f000000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy#00000000386f16b400000000468302f4#, &Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig#00000000386f173e00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler#00000000386f17c600000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\Validator#00000000386f17df00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\Storage#00000000386f17dd00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager#00000000386f168b00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory#00000000386f168700000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor#00000000386f165700000000468302f4#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php:101]
#5 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->__construct(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000386f16f000000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy#00000000386f16b400000000468302f4#, &Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig#00000000386f173e00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler#00000000386f17c600000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\Validator#00000000386f17df00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\Storage#00000000386f17dd00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager#00000000386f168b00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory#00000000386f168700000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor#00000000386f165700000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy#00000000386f17de00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface\Proxy#00000000386f175900000000468302f4#, &Magento\Backend\App\Config#00000000386f174700000000468302f4#) called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php:14]
#6 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->__construct(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000386f16f000000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy#00000000386f16b400000000468302f4#, &Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig#00000000386f173e00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler#00000000386f17c600000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\Validator#00000000386f17df00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\Storage#00000000386f17dd00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager#00000000386f168b00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory#00000000386f168700000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor#00000000386f165700000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy#00000000386f17de00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface\Proxy#00000000386f175900000000468302f4#, &Magento\Backend\App\Config#00000000386f174700000000468302f4#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116]
#7 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Backend\...', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000386f16f000000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy#00000000386f16b400000000468302f4#, &Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig#00000000386f173e00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler#00000000386f17c600000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\Validator#00000000386f17df00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Session\Storage#00000000386f17dd00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager#00000000386f168b00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory#00000000386f168700000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor#00000000386f165700000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy#00000000386f17de00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface\Proxy#00000000386f175900000000468302f4#, &Magento\Backend\App\Config#00000000386f174700000000468302f4#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#8 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Backend\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#9 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Backend\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:160]
#10 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(array('instance' => 'Magento\Backend\...'), 'Magento\Backend\...', NULL, 'authStorage', 'Magento\Backend\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:246]
#11 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\Backend\...', array(array('eventManager', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('backendData', 'Magento\Backend\...', true, NULL), array('authStorage', 'Magento\Backend\...', true, NULL), array('credentialStorag...', 'Magento\Backend\...', true, NULL), array('coreConfig', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('modelFactory', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL)), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#12 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\Backend\...', array(array('eventManager', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('backendData', 'Magento\Backend\...', true, NULL), array('authStorage', 'Magento\Backend\...', true, NULL), array('credentialStorag...', 'Magento\Backend\...', true, NULL), array('coreConfig', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('modelFactory', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL)), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#13 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Backend\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#14 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Backend\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:160]
#15 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(array('instance' => 'Magento\Backend\...'), 'Magento\Backend\...', NULL, 'auth', 'Magento\Backend\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:246]
#16 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\Backend\...', array(array('auth', 'Magento\Backend\...', true, NULL), array('formKeyValidator', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('backendUrl', 'Magento\Backend\...', true, NULL), array('redirectFactory', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('rawResultFactory', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL)), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#17 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\Backend\...', array(array('auth', 'Magento\Backend\...', true, NULL), array('formKeyValidator', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('backendUrl', 'Magento\Backend\...', true, NULL), array('redirectFactory', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('rawResultFactory', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL)), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#18 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Backend\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#19 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Backend\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:196]
#20 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray(array('csrf_validator' => array('instance' => 'CsrfRequestValid...'), 'http_method_vali...' => array('instance' => 'Magento\Framewor...'))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:172]
#21 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(array('csrf_validator' => array('instance' => 'CsrfRequestValid...'), 'http_method_vali...' => array('instance' => 'Magento\Framewor...')), NULL, NULL, 'validators', 'RequestValidator') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:246]
#22 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('RequestValidator', array(array('validators', NULL, true, NULL)), array('validators' => array('csrf_validator' => array('instance' => 'CsrfRequestValid...'), 'http_method_vali...' => array('instance' => 'Magento\Framewor...')))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#23 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('RequestValidator', array(array('validators', NULL, true, NULL)), array('validators' => array('csrf_validator' => array('instance' => 'CsrfRequestValid...'), 'http_method_vali...' => array('instance' => 'Magento\Framewor...')))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#24 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('RequestValidator') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#25 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('RequestValidator') called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:71]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->__construct(&Magento\Framework\App\RouterList#00000000386f171d00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000386f168500000000468302f4#, NULL, NULL, NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:14]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->__construct(&Magento\Framework\App\RouterList#00000000386f171d00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000386f168500000000468302f4#, NULL, NULL, NULL) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116]
#28 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewor...', array(&Magento\Framework\App\RouterList#00000000386f171d00000000468302f4#, &Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000386f168500000000468302f4#, NULL, NULL, NULL)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#29 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewor...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#30 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewor...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:136]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#00000000386f168200000000468302f4#) called at [index.php:41]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the memory_limit and the session lifetime in the .htaccess files of root folder or in pub directory.